# SQL Replication Publisher thinks Subscriber is wrong version

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replication

I have two SQL Server 2008 instances, one running Workgroup Edition (publisher) and the other Standard (subscriber)

I am trying to replicate a database but I am getting errors when it tries to create the database at the subscriber because it thinks it is running SQL Server 2005 for some reason.

Has anyone had this issue before?

I am getting this error

> Column Location in object Members contains type Geography, which
>   is not supported in the target server version, SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked compatibility mode for the databases?

For example:

```
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'YourDBName';
```